# typescript: value type to represent any of the primitive type

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the best way to define a property which can take any of `string`,`number` and `boolean` primitive values. I need a property to accept any of these primitive type as value from an html input field (which can be text/int/bool). having `any` miss type safety I was looking for (specifically, it should not be object, function type).

Comment: It is not possible since TypeScript does not have TypeUnions. You can vote for this feature request here : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1364

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function that accepts those, not a property.

To make the function specifically only accept `string`, `number` and `boolean` you would use an overload. The implementation signature (which is typed `any`) isn't actually callable, so it doesn't allow other types.

```
class Example {
    storeMyThing(input: number): void;
    storeMyThing(input: boolean): void;
    storeMyThing(input: string): void;
    storeMyThing(input: any) {
        console.log(typeof input);
        console.log(input);
    }
}

var example = new Example();

// Yes
example.storeMyThing(1);
example.storeMyThing(true);
example.storeMyThing('String');

// No
example.storeMyThing(['Arr', 'Arr']);
example.storeMyThing({ prop: 'val'});
```

Comment: thanks. why is `storeMyThing(input: any)` not callable? doesn't`storeMyThing(input: any) {...}` define a function? sorry I am new to the syntax, and looks like it defines a public function.

Comment: Worth mentioning the good'ol vote here link : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1364 :)

Comment: @bsr the "implementation signature" is hidden, because it must be compatible with all of the overloads, which often means the type ends up being `any`. If it wasn't hidden, it would allow everything. This is part of the overload design in the language.

Comment: thanks steve. If I remove all 3 overloads (line 2,3,4) and does't make any other changes, it gets the any version and no error. interesting. with your explanation, it makes sense. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 15):

Since Typescript 1.4 you can create a union type like this:

```
type Primitive = string | boolean | number;
```

And use it like this:

```
function acceptPrimitive(prim: Primitive) {
  // prim is of a primitive type
}
```